# SQL Server Data Tools and Edmx

Tags: entity-framework, azure, sql-server-data-tools

So we're using the new SSDT Microsoft released, pretty cool stuff. We are keeping a database project under version control with all the schemas, and an offline database for development and we can later deploy on SQL Azure database. We;re using EF in development, so my question is where would the edmx fit in, should we update the edmx file from the offline database or from the online SQL Azure directly, whats the best practice on this?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that in your case "the production database is the truth", so I would update from SQL Azure. There's no right answer tho really.

Incidentally, in the early betas of SSDT it was possible to have a reference from an EDMX to a SSDT project thus your source code became the truth (which, in my opinion, is preferable) and the EDMX knew it was always working against "the truth". Unfortunately they ditched this feature and there are no signs of it returning.

Answer (score 0):

For the EF to work correctly the EDMX file has to be in-synch with the database you are connecting to. It's hard to answer your question without knowing the development process you follow but I would imagine you use Sql Azure in production and develop against an on-premises database. Therefore one copy of the Edmx file will be used on production server. In the development environment you have a "living" copy of the edmx file that is changed as needed when the local database changes. When you get to the point you when you are ready to ship you deploy your app (include the edmx file) to a production environment that uses Sql Azure.
If, in your development environment, you update the edmx file from the SQL Azure then stuff will break or will not work correctly if the schema of the database in Azure is different from schema of your local database.